# Covert Symbolic Link folder to Hard Link Folder

Tags: java, symlink

I created a symbolic Link folder which contains list of files. Is there any way to convert the Symbolic Link to HardLink using java?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Hard links are rarely a good idea.

Comment: Did you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html?

Comment: @Eli sadoff Requirement is like that . three folders source-temp-destination. Source to temp they required to use symbolic links. Once the final modification is done. They need to move the files in temp folder to destination and remove the temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

To create a hard link using java, you can use :

```
Path newLink = ...;
Path existingFile = ...;
try {
    Files.createLink(newLink, existingFile);
} catch (IOException x) {
   System.err.println(x);
} catch (UnsupportedOperationException x) {
   // Some file systems do not
   // support adding an existing
   // file to a directory.
   System.err.println(x);
}
```

So, in your case `newLink` should be the `oldSymbolicLink` that you've created, and the `existingFile` represent its target.

To get the target of a symbolic link you may use

```
Files.readSymbolicLink(oldSymbolicLink));
```

---

**Oracle Doc:** [Links, Symbolic or Otherwise](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html)

Comment: It will not work if we create hardlink from the symbolic link folder, right?

Answer (score 0):

The [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html) as pointed out by others says that hard links on directories cannot be created. So, instead of telling you how to create hard link to directories, I am going to explain why you cannot create hard link on directories.

Hardlinks are on directories can cause loops when you are trying to traverse the directory tree.

For example if you have a directory `/foo/bar` and a symbolic link `/foo/bar/baz` pointing to `../bar`, when you try to traverse this tree, you will run into an infinite loop.

```
/foo/
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/baz
/foo/bar/baz/bar
/foo/bar/baz/bar/baz
...
```

Now, if `baz` is a symlink to `../bar`, it is simple to fix by unlinking `baz` using the `unlink(2)` system call (because unlink does not follow symlinks). However, if `baz` was a hard link, it would have been much `harder` (no pun intended) to fix this. In the book "Advanced Programming in Unix Environment", Stephen Rago notes that Rich Stevens corrupted his file system while trying this experiment (and `fsck` was unable to recover it)